# WPF ListBox ExtendedMode Move selected item with IsSelected binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Simple ListBox with `SelectionMode="Extended"` binds to viewmodels with `IsSelected` property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=list}" />
<ListBox x:Name="list"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         ItemsSource="{Binding listItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">    
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

When you select zero item and then do

```
listItems.Move(0, 1);
```

ListBox `SelectedItems.Count` increased from 1 to 2. After increasing that counter such way, it will decrement by one when you select random items in listbox.

Why SelectedItems accumulates moved items and is there fix?

ViewModels:

```
class MainVM : VMBase
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        listItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { 
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> listItems { get; set; }
}

public class Item : VMBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What typeis `listItems`? What's `Move`?

Comment: You still haven't shown what is `Move`.

Comment: It is ObservableCollection<T>.Move

Comment: gotcha. What is your desired behavior in that case? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to move items in ListBox using [gong dragdrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop). It internally [uses](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/blob/af62c880954eec034000f851821d9ce5e38c885a/GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop/Utilities/ItemsControlExtensions.cs#L229) LsitBox.SelectedItems, and here I met up this strange behaviour. Desired behavior - SelectedItems containing actually selected items.

Comment: oky I see, and what havew you tried to solve this problem, so far?

Comment: Unselect before move() and reselect after seems to work as well as `var t1 = listItems[1]; listItems.RemoveAt(1); listItems.Insert(2, t1);` - but that is not solution and causes side effects in my app (eg saving when unselect item). So I do that: `private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.AddedItems != null)
 {
  foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
  {
   if (list.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>().Where(i => i == item).Count() > 1)
   {
    list.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
   }
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing comes from this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If you remove that, it'll work, eg, it won't duplicate the items. It kind of seems they are incompatible.

Either keep using your solution, if it seems to work and if there's nothing wrong.

You can also solve this by subscribing into "ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged" event and listening for `Moved` action, where you do something similiar what you already do.

Alternatively, if you're willing to change things a little: namely, you could give up "TwoWay" binding, in order to make this work, as so:

`<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
         Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`

This will still update your viewmodel `IsSelected` property, but changing it in the vm side, won't do anything. If you need that functionality, you could think about injecting it into viewmodel through interface/command.